# Is this best practice for updating mongodb object with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, spark-java

I'm using MongoDB and Morphia in my SparkJava project. This is a new adventure for me right now. I'm wondering if this is the best way to update and existing object in the database? Is there a better way if I want to replace an update the complete document ?

Example update method in my ContentBlockDao

```
@Override
public ContentBlock update(ContentBlock contentBlock) throws DaoException {
    Query<ContentBlock> query = datastore.createQuery(ContentBlock.class)
            .field("id").equal(new ObjectId(contentBlock.getId()));
    UpdateOperations<ContentBlock> updateOperations = setValuesForUpdate(
                                                        datastore.createUpdateOperations(ContentBlock.class),
                                                        contentBlock);

   datastore.update(query, updateOperations);

    return query.get();
}

private UpdateOperations setValuesForUpdate(UpdateOperations<ContentBlock> updateOperations,
                                            ContentBlock contentBlock) {

    updateOperations.set("html", contentBlock.getHtml());
    updateOperations.set("lastUpdater", contentBlock.getLastUpdater());

    return updateOperations;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let morphia manage object updates for you.

Use save method for complete document replacement. Creates a new document if `_id` is not present in the entity else replace document.

```
<T> Key<T> save(T entity);
```

Use merge method for selective field updates. This will compare the dbobject with the input entity and update the fields that changed.

```
<T> Key<T> merge(T entity)
```

For any other query criteria you can use update method.

```
<T> UpdateResults update(T entity, UpdateOperations<T> var2);
```

Comment: I've tried save but for whatever reason I end up seeing the same object duplicated in the document with the same _id. I'm not sure why this is happening. 

I send in a json string and convert it to  a ContentBlock object and then save it.

Comment: Are you sure its `_id` not `id` because `_id` field has unique constraint in MongoDB ? Try annotating the id field with `@Id` annotation in `ContentBlock` class. You can add your `ContentBlock` object along with a sample json string and conversion code if the issue persists.